# IIS - Is it possible to have different access levels on different directories of a website?

Tags: iis, iis-7, web, authorization, port

I am looking for a way to restrict access to one of directories withing my website to be accessible via a specific port number (i.e. 5353) not by port 80.

Is that possible to be done in IIS level?

Comment: Do you have admin access to the server via RDP?

Comment: Yes I do have admin access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing following steps:

1- Redirects the calls to my directory to a dead-url so 404 will occurs if this directory or subpages we called.
2- Copy original website physical files 
3- created a new website with a port assigned to it (5335) and mapped to newly created files
4- Created a virtual directory for those folders that needed to keep their changes and pointed them to the original location.

Done...